# Dplyr: Anonymising values up to a million rows with unique names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(
  region = c('all', 'one', 'eleven', 'six'),
  forename = c('John', 'Jane', 'Rich', 'Clive'),
  surname = c('Smith', 'Jones', 'Smith', 'Jones'))
```

I would like to anonymise the values within the 'forename ' and 'surname ' variables so that the data looks like this.

```
d <- tibble(
  region = c('all', 'one', 'eleven', 'six'),
  forename = c('forename1', 'forename2', 'forename3', 'forename4'),
  surname = c('surname1', 'surname2', 'surname3', 'surname4'))
```

I could just do this manually but I have a df with millions of rows. What I would like is for the row number in the df to coincide with the value rename. So the data on row 67 for example would show:

```
d <- tibble(
  region = c('all'),
  forename = c('forename67'),
  surname = c('surname67'))
```

Does anyone know how I would achieve this using dplyr if possible?

Thannks

Answer (score 1):

As every row is a unique user, we can paste `row_number` to the column names.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
 mutate(forename = paste0("forename", row_number()), 
        surname = paste0("surname", row_number()))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  region forename  surname 
#  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>   
#1 all    forename1 surname1
#2 one    forename2 surname2
#3 eleven forename3 surname3
#4 six    forename4 surname4
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
d %>%
    mutate(forename = str_c("forename", row_number()),
            surname = str_c("surname", row_number()))
```

---

Or with `lapply` from `base R`

```
d[c('forename', 'surname')] <- lapply(c('forename', 'surname'), function(x) 
         paste0(x, seq_len(nrow(d))))]
```